# matomo delay in content impression

Tags: javascript, tracking, matomo, dynamic-content, user-tracking

I'm trying to track some content with Matomo's [tracking-client](https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript).

After initializing the client my snippet is like this:

```
window.matomoAsyncInit = function () {

        console.log('track start');

        try {
            var contentTracker = Matomo.getTracker('...Host...', '...');
            contentTracker.trackAllContentImpressions();
        } catch( err ) {}
    };
```

Everything works well except for a timeout of 3 seconds between the log-message 'track start' and the request to matomo-server.
Is there any configuration or option to reduce this delay?

Comment: Verified it by myself:
The delay comes from the request queue.
The content impressions don't get lost. They may not get logged by the browser.

It is possible to switch off the queue. But this would lead to a lot more requests to matomo-server.

Comment: The option to switch off the queue is: ``contentTracker.disableQueueRequest()``